# how to i get shortcode outside of wordpress?

Tags: plugins, wordpress, shortcode

how can i get shortcode outside of wordpress?

this is my code

```
<?php 
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php'); 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
);
$latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $latest_posts->the_post();
if (preg_match_all ("#\[scode\](.+)\[\/scode\]#", the_content(), $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
echo $matches[1];
};
?>
```

and this is my content

```
[scode]hare is my shortcode[/scode]
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,

when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
```

anyone can help plz...

Comment: Just call the function that the shortcode is hooked to and pass it the parameters that you would normally do so through the shortcode.  Better question though is why do you need to display these posts outside of WordPress?  I bet you can just create a custom template to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use [do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]')](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode).  It returns a string, so you call it like : `<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]'); ?>`.

In your example, you can probably do something like:

```
<?php 
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php'); 
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
    ;
    $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
    if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $latest_posts->the_post();
    if (preg_match_all ("#". do_shortcode('[scode]') ."(.+)". do_shortcode('[scode]') ."#", the_content(), $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    echo $matches[1];
    };
?>
```

Comment: i don't want to use do_shortcode,
i'm using this code in my plugin = 
add_shortcode( 'scode', 'my_function' );
now how can i get this code under scode?

Answer (score 0):

That's possible. There's a composer package that allows you to create wordpress like shortcodes in any PHP application: https://github.com/maiorano84/shortcodes

You can find a tutorial here: https://www.codediesel.com/php/adding-wordpress-like-shortcodes-to-your-web-applications/